# Trouble using multiple instances of a jQuery UI control on a page. Multiple uses of the accordion control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

On the page I am making, I need to use the jQuery UI accordion control twice. I am able to use it one time with no problems, but when I try to use it add another one on the same page, the first one stops working and the second one IS working.

Any ideas?

[Link to the code](http://pastie.org/2886773)

Comment: can you add some code. Some people setup a http://jsfiddle.net page for this type of questions.

Comment: Show us the code, young Skywalker.

Comment: [would this help you?](http://pastie.org/2886773)

I want to be able to use the accordion control twice in the page.

Comment: Hmmmm, I may have figured something out. It seems I have using the id of "Accordion" twice. Should I make the id a class and then just change the css code to reflect the changes?

Comment: Yeah try changing it to a class and see if that fixes it. Duplicating IDs could introduce issues because they are designed to be unique, looks like you already know that though :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same ID in the same page - per [W3C specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). Depending on which browser renders the content - you won't get the same behavior. You need to use classes or custom attributes to trigger the accordion behavior. IE is one browser that will not handle elements with repeating element IDs (other browsers are more lenient with the spec).